# Detecting if an alert with a specific window name appears using Marathon Testing Tool/Ruby

Tags: ruby, marathontesting

I currently am using Marathon (Java Automation tool for testing) that runs a Ruby script on a Java application and need to detect if a specific alert appears. For example, I want it to press "Accept" on a row in a while loop and handle potential pop-up alerts during the process.

Only 2 pop-ups can appear during this process of accepting.

If a popup with the window title "Are you sure?" appears, I want it to press enter or click "OK" as usual.

But, if a popup with the window title "Message" (which indicates error), I want it to press "OK" and exit the while loop. Exiting the while loop should be trivial to code after I figure out a way to differentiate the two pop-ups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `get_window` and check the title with what you are expecting. Alternatively you can execute arbitrary Java code using `driver.execute_script` that can look for alert windows and do the needful.

```
#{{{ Marathon
require_fixture 'default'
#}}} Marathon

def test

    with_window("SwingSet3") {
        select("JOptionPane", "true")

        option = Random.rand(2)

        if(option == 0)
          click("Show Warning Dialog")
        else
          click("Show Confirmation Dialog")
        end

        if(get_window == "Warning Dialog Example")
          with_window("Warning Dialog Example") {
              click("OK")
          }
        end

        if(get_window == "Select an Option")
          with_window("Select an Option") {
              click("Yes")
          }

          with_window("Message") {
              click("OK")
          }
        end
    }

end
```